# SQL/Python - Recursively joining id columns

Tags: python, sql, graph-theory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

I have a SQL table with 2 columns - a_id and b_id (a_id has a many-to-many relationship with b_id). I am trying to join all a_ids with all linked a_ids and b_ids. e.g.

| a_id | b_id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| D | 3 |

should result in:

[A,D] : [1,3]

[B,C] : [2]

It doesn't matter too much what the final format is as I can pivot/explode it to be flat again.

I am currently using a while loop to iteratively join the data to itself on b_id, then group by a_id and concatenate all corresponding a_ids and b_ids into an array, then flattening the array and joining again etc. As I have millions of rows of data this code is taking hours to run and I am wondering if there is quicker way to do this using SQL and python. This is the code I am currently using:

```
def join_to_self():

        connection.execute('''
            CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE joined_data as
                (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                       j.b_id as b_id,
                       j.a_id as a_id1,
                       jo.a_id as a_id2
            from temp_data as j
                full outer join temp_data as jo
                on j.b_id = jo.b_id );''')


def find_matches():

    connection.execute('''CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp_data as
            (
            with agg_matches as(
            SELECT
                    g.a_id1,
                    array_agg(distinct g.b_id) as b_ids,
                    array_agg(distinct g.a_id2) as a_id2
            FROM joined_data g
            GROUP BY g.a_id1
                  )
            SELECT DISTINCT
                   cast(A.value as varchar) as a_id,
                   cast(B.value as int) AS b_id
            FROM   agg_matches,
                   Table(Flatten(agg_matches.b_ids)) B,
                   Table(Flatten(agg_matches.a_id2 )) A);''')

    number_rows = connection.execute(''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  joined_data'').fetchone()

   
return number_rows[0]

    
join_to_self()

stop = True

while stop:

    previous_rows = find_matches()

    join_to_self()
    current_rows = find_matches()

    if previous_rows == current_rows:
        stop = False
```

Comment: When you say "hours to run" is that for one query, or for the whole process? How many times does the query run to go through?

Answer (score 0):

Identifying clusters of points is a graph-walking problem, which in SQL requires a recursive CTE. You would first generate all the edges, then traverse the graph while keeping track of already-visited edges, and finally identify each group by the smallest common edge:

```
with 
    edges as (
        select t1.a_id as a_id1, t2.a_id as a_id2
        from temp_data t1
        inner join temp_data t2 on t1.b_id = t2.b_id
    ),
    cte as (
        select a_id1, a_id2, array_construct(a_id1) as visited 
        from edges 
        where a_id1 = a_id2
        union all
        select c.a_id1, e.a_id2, array_append(c.visited, e.a_id2)
        from cte c
        inner join edges e on e.a_id1 = c.a_id2
        where not array_contains(e.a_id2, c.visited)
    )
select a_id1, dense_rank() over(order by min(a_id2)) as grp
from cte
group by a_id1
order by grp, a_id1
```

This puts each `a_id` in a separate row, along with the group it belongs to. If you want the result as an array, along with te corresponding `b_id`, you can change the outer query to:

```
with ...
select array_agg(distinct t.a_id) as a_ids, array_agg(distinct t.b_id) as b_ids
from temp_data t
inner join (
    select a_id1, dense_rank() over(order by min(a_id2)) as grp
    from cte
    group by a_id1
) x on x.a_id1 = t.a_id
group by x.grp
```